# How can we send events to a wpf client application from chrome extension

Tags: c#, google-chrome, .net-core, named-pipes, chrome-native-messaging

I had created a chrome app with c# host. I would like to record the events in the chrome extension using the c# application and play from the application, for that, I had created an additional C# WPF application that holds a button record. How can I trigger the record feature from the button click?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called: **UI Automation** and, for that, there are plenty of libraries and tutorials.

I have implemented in the past UI Automation from Windows Apps to any platform (Windows, Mac, Linux, Web and Citrix). BUT,never from browser to Windows App (It is possible, take as example the well known Chrome extension of op.gg on which they created it to send UI automation to League Of Legends client.

Comment: is it possible to do manually without any automation libraries, I mean using some IPC kinds of stuff.